# How do I generate a random 2D map for an iOS application?

Tags: ios, random, 2d, terrain, generated

I would like to be able to generate random terrain and store it in a file, but I'm not sure of the file type or how to generate it. I'm not really sure where to start and would appreciate any advice. I would not like to use any third party programs to do it, because I'd like to understand it fully. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As I am not sure what is meant by "2D map" by the OP (could be a geographical map with roads and stuffs, a map of tiles for a game like in Andrey's answer, or a 2D elevation map like an heightfield to generate a terrain for 3D applications), I will focus on elevation maps which are, IMHO, harder than tile-based 2D maps for 2D games and easier than geographical maps.

For elevation maps, several options:

- generate a set of random values and low-pass filter them. Using an FFT to do the low pass filtering, you'll obtain a tileable heightfield.
- use Perlin noise.
- based on Perlin noise and fractional brownian motions, several variations are described in "Texturing and Modeling: a Procedural Approach" (Perlin and Musgrave). Namely, for example, hetero-terrains, ridged multifractals, warped ridged multifractals etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x). It covers in detail and in plain language how to make a map

Answer (score -1):

Use [Cocous2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) and it has Cocous2dBuilder. I think it will help you to build terrain